# How can I move the transform randomly in ping pong?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First I generate new objects in this example 1000 objects over the terrain in height 10 in random positions :

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class CloneObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Terrain terrain;
    public GameObject prefab;
    public GameObject parent;
    [Range(10, 1000)]
    public int numberOfObjects;
    public float yOffset = 10f;

    private float terrainWidth;
    private float terrainLength;
    private float xTerrainPos;
    private float zTerrainPos;

    void Start()
    {
        //Get terrain size
        terrainWidth = terrain.terrainData.size.x;
        terrainLength = terrain.terrainData.size.z;

        //Get terrain position
        xTerrainPos = terrain.transform.position.x;
        zTerrainPos = terrain.transform.position.z;

        generateObjectOnTerrain();
    }

    void generateObjectOnTerrain()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
        {
            //Generate random x,z,y position on the terrain
            float randX = UnityEngine.Random.Range(xTerrainPos, xTerrainPos + terrainWidth);
            float randZ = UnityEngine.Random.Range(zTerrainPos, zTerrainPos + terrainLength);
            float yVal = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(new Vector3(randX, 0, randZ));

            //Apply Offset if needed
            yVal = yVal + yOffset;

            //Generate the Prefab on the generated position
            GameObject objInstance = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(randX, yVal, randZ), Quaternion.identity);
            objInstance.name = "Waypoint";
            objInstance.tag = "Waypoint";
            objInstance.transform.parent = parent.transform;
        }
    }
}
```

The result is :

[image: Objects randomly over terrain]

And then on each object there is a script attached :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * 3, Random.Range(2f, 9f)), transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the objects are not moving in ping pong from the original spawned positions like in the screenshot on the top the first screenshot but they are all moving first to the edge of the terrain and making the ping pong there :

[image: Objects make ping pong but moved all to the edge of the terrain]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PingPong is a lot like Lerp. You need to supply a time value to it, not a delta time. As such, you'll want to store the initial object height, and work out how high you want to pingpong on top of that.

This example code will do just that:

```
    public float Speed;
    private float intitialY;
    private float pingPongHeight;
    
    private void Start ( )
    {
        intitialY = transform.localPosition.y;
        pingPongHeight = UnityEngine.Random.Range ( 2f, 9f );
    }

    private void Update ( )
    {
        var height = Mathf.PingPong ( Time.time * Speed, pingPongHeight );
        var position = transform.localPosition;
        position.y = intitialY + height;
        transform.localPosition = position;
    }
```

I've assumed you used a random value to determine how high each object will travel over the course of the pingpong.